# If $A_n$ is an event, $X_n = \mathbb{1}_{A_n}$, and $X = 0$, why does $X_n \to X$ in probability imply $P(A_n) \to 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

If $A_n$ is an event, $X_n = \mathbb{1}_{A_n}$, and $X = 0$, why does $X_n \to X$ in probability imply $P(A_n) \to 0$? I know that this means that $\forall \epsilon >0$, $P(|\mathbb{1}_{A_n}| \geq \epsilon) \to 0$, but don't know where to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varepsilon=1/2$, and note that
$$\{|1_{A_n}|\geq \varepsilon\}=\{1_{A_n}\geq 1/2\}=A_n,$$
such that if $1_{A_n}\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow}0$, then even 
$$P(A_n)=P(|1_{A_n}|\geq \varepsilon)\rightarrow 0,$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Indicators only take the values 0 and 1. So if the absolute value of the indicator is at least some positive number, it must be 1.